# Is there a way to prevent code contracts from crashing Visual Studio 2010 SP1?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, code-contracts

I am using Visual Studio 2010 SP1 Ultimate, and some of my colleagues are using Visual Studio 2010 SP1 Professional. We have all [installed code contracts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/dd491992.aspx). Is there anyway to prevent Visual Studio from crashing given the below scenarios?

We have found 2 out of 3 visual studio professional installations to crash in the following situation:

> Contracts are defined in a class that is "bootstrapped" by WebActivator. Visual studio crashes when then opening an MVC 3 view with razor syntax (*.cshtml)

We have found Visual Studio Ultimate to crash in the following situation:

> We have defined interface contracts that are tied to abstract concrete contract classes. Visual Studio crashes when commenting out the concrete classes but leaving the attribute on the associated interface and then compiling.

Comment: Do you have a short repro that shows the problem, provided it is still a problem with the latest CodeContract installer?

Comment: Thanks for following up. No. We ended up removing code contracts from the project.